# How is it possible that we can solve some equations numerically, but can't solve them analytically?

Tags: intuition

For example, there is the [Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) that states there is no analytical solution to polynomial equations of degree five or higher, mentioning $x^5-x-1=0$ as the simplest example. Now if we take $$x^5-x-a=0$$ we can calculate $x$ numerically for every value of $a$ without any trouble. So clearly all the information necessary is contained in the equation. But despite this, we are not able to provide a formula like $x(a)=\dots$.

How is it possible that *we have all the information necessary*, but we still can not shape it into an explicit formula? What property is it that makes some equations solvable analytically, and others not?

Comment: Oh, but you **can** provide a formula like $x(a) = \ldots.$ You just have to invent some parts of it. Tons of mathematics consists of functions that people invented in order to be able to solve problems. For example, $x = \sin(10^\circ)$ solves a problem that is just as "unsolvable" as $x^5-x-a=0.$

Comment: Considering we have only finitely many mathematical functions and constants we care to have given names and uncountably many real numbers, this is really no surprise.

Comment: Asking for analytic solutions alone is very restrictive. So I guess by formula you mean a finite expression in the elementary function. Otherwise we can express every solution of such equations by a formula. In fact that is what a numerical solution is -- it is just a truncated form of an infinite expression representing the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it mean to solve a problem analytically? Finding "analytic" solutions to a cubic polynomial, I might have to write down numbers like $3^{1/3}$. What is $3^{1/3}$? Is that considered "analytic" to you? Radicals are just ways to write down a family of numbers not equal to the integers and not equal to a fraction of integers, just like how fractions are a way to write down numbers that are not equal to an integer. That theorem states that there are solutions to degree 5+ polynomials that cannot be stated in terms of integers, fractions, and radicals (read the first sentence of the wiki page). But like we did with radicals, we can invent a new way to write down this new class of numbers. I forgot what they are called but they are often written like $B(4)$, just like how $4^{1/4}$ is a thing. Writing down something "analytically" really depends on how you define analytic.

Comment: Just found this cool table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Mathematical_expressions. Guess what I call "analytical solution" is actually a closed-form expression. "Mathematical expression" seems to be the most general category, so could we come up with a mathematical expression like $x(a)=\dots$? Or do the symbols we would need just not exist (yet)?

Comment: @MaxD No, they exist and are well understood. Check out algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain the analytical solution of the equation but you can obtain explicit asymptotic expressions of $x$.

To simplify the notations, let $a=b^5$ and we shall try to solve
$$x^5-x-b^5=0$$ assuming $b>0$. Using high-order methods (order $n$) we shall have
$$x_{0}=b+\frac{b}{5 b^4-1}$$
$$x_{1}=b+\frac{5 b^5-b}{25 b^8+1}$$
$$x_{2}=b+\frac{25 b^9+b}{125 b^{12}+25 b^8+5 b^4-1}$$
$$x_{3}=b+\frac{125 b^{13}+25 b^9+5 b^5-b}{625 b^{16}+250 b^{12}+50 b^8-5 b^4+1}$$
$$x_{4}=b+\frac{625 b^{17}+250 b^{13}+50 b^9-5 b^5+b}{3125 b^{20}+1875 b^{16}+500 b^{12}+6   b^4-1}$$
$$x_{5}=b+\frac{3125 b^{21}+1875 b^{17}+500 b^{13}+6 b^5-b}{15625 b^{24}+12500 b^{20}+4375 b^{16}+375 b^{12}+35 b^8-7 b^4+1}$$ Suppose that we do this forever.

Using $b=3$, some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_{n} & \text{decimal representation} \\
 0 & \frac{1215}{404} & 3.007425742574257425742574 \\
 1 & \frac{246645}{82013} & 3.007389072464121541706803 \\
 2 & \frac{100137870}{33297277} & 3.007389162783491274676905 \\
 3 & \frac{6254765325}{2079799117} & 3.007389162671713933610637 \\
 4 & \frac{33012650893518}{10977179575985} & 3.007389162671662103584418 \\
 5 & \frac{13403136063083787}{4456734841451944} & 3.007389162671662635777060 \\
6 & \frac{680209145067512871}{226179289833989464} &3.007389162671662634787269 \\
7 & \frac{2209319270264084987187}{734630322436023080017} & 3.007389162671662634787290 \\
8 & \frac{896983610363648795857113}{298259906465446908872354} & 3.007389162671662634787294
\end{array}
\right)$$